# Matlab to C with Matlab coder for streaming data

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

I am using convolution function in Matlab to verify my algorithm. When I convert this to C code to be run in an embedded system, I want it to process real time data coming from a sensor input, i.e. 1 sample at a time. Instead of the batch mode operation in Matlab.

Currently when I use Matlab Coder to convert this code, the C code is also in batch mode. Is there any way I can do this? thank you!

Comment: You're probably better off asking the mathworks support, they're usually quite helpful. I don't think you'll find a sizeable matlab-coder audience on SO...

Comment: You need to write your MATLAB code to do what you want in C code. Or you can build a buffer around your batch mode code.